# Rotate images with biggest side (image width) to be the vertical side

Tags: imagemagick, rotate

Rotate images with biggest side (image width) to be the vertical side

You can see the problem here:
Imagemagic / gimp and other tools fails to orient photos concisely.
I am searching for a tool that can Rotate images with biggest side (image width) to be the vertical (or the horizontal) side irrelevant of image exif data.

Look here about the problem:

https://github.com/ImageMagick/ImageMagick/issues/6127

Comment: Are you OK to do rotate only to a files with portrait orientation (to make them landscape)?

Comment: And are you OK to use different tool?

Comment: yes, i am ok to use different tools. I found all images with wrong orientation and try to chnage them. But this is a manual process.. I would like to automate it...

Comment: @Estatistics I'm not sure I understood everything because your English is a bit chaotic, but from what I see, the problem is the opposite to what you seem to be thinking - missing EXIF data. Proper orientation EXIF would tell magick how to convert it (with e.g. `mogrify -auto-orient *.jpg`), not sure why you deleted it. As long as it existed, of course. Do you still have original pictures with original EXIF?

Comment: No, i have not them.

Comment: @Estatistics then I'm not sure if there's a good automatic solution to your problem now. If you take a look at both images, one is `2595x2548`and rotated correctly, other is `2573x1709` and rotated incorrectly. So you don't want to rotate if width is bigger than height. Normally you'd do that with `mogrify -rotate "-90>" *.jpg` but it rotates both.

Comment: I can think of a way, a headless image viewer or similar, to check what side IS DISPLAYED vertically, &whatsnot.Then u rotate only those pics that their highest side isnt the vertical one that is displayed.One problem remains, what is the "up" or down side of the pic. Here AI may be implemented but this is another question. In my case, when exif data are deleted / lost, those pics  that are displayed wrongly, must be rotated 90o left.  In what logic GIMP display one vertically & other horizontally? If we know that logic, then we can take counter measures. Cause itsnot based onthe highest side.

Comment: Well, if you'd like to play around with AI and look for solutions like that that aren't 100% reliable then sure, but rotating images manually with any sort of gallery that supports keyboard shortcut for that would likely be a lot faster, even if you got a lot of images in that set.